# (Graph Convolutional Network (GCN) based recommender system maintenance issue

Tags: deep-learning, recommender-system, model-evaluations, graph-neural-network, knowledge-graph

I have built an item-item **recommender model** using (Graph Convolutional Network **(GCN)** for an **E-commerce website**. Could you please help me with the maintenance of the model.

1. How often should I retrain the model after deployment?( 1 month, 2 months)
2. What are the main metrics which I should track after deployment to evaluate the model?
3. Any suggestions related to Train/valid/test split ratios (such as 70:15:15 or 60:20:20)
4. Any materials related to model maintenance/recommder systems evaluation post deployment would be of great help.

Thank you

Comment: there is no definite answer, it all depends on the usage and your problem domain